# $.ajax JSON data to PHP is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an inline image string which I am sending to PHP using $.ajax.

**I am not able to get the data sent from JavaScript in PHP. using $_POST** However, I am able to get the Server (PHP) response back.

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

**JavaScript Snippet**

```
var data1 = {
"username": $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username,
"blob": $scope.cropper.croppedImage     
};
data = $.param(data);   

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    data: data1,
    processData: false,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        var servRet = data;

        if(servRet.error > 0)
        {           
            alert(servRet.errorMsg);
            return;         
        }
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

**PHP SNIPPET**

```
<?php

// Return Values for Jason
$errorCode                  = 0;
$errorMsg                   = "NONE";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$errorMsg = $_POST;
}

$retData = array('error' => $errorCode , 'errorMsg' => $errorMsg);
echo json_encode($retData);

?>
```

Comment: what happends if you change your URL to > /MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php ..... dont start url in AJAX with http or whatever its not allowed if i remember correctly

Comment: Have you inspect `$_POST` using `print_r($_POST)` ? Check that. If your image is larger than POST size, it might be cause of failure.

Comment: check your `$.param(data);` maybe typo error. your declare `var data1` in previous line

Comment: Lauw: You were correct in highlighting URL Problem. When I changed the URL to  /MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php from "http://localhost/MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php", things srarted working. Thanks for timely comment ! ! !

Answer (score 0):

The response comes back fine when I test it. The only problem (aside from the typo where you changed the variable name from `data` to `data1` half way through the code and then swapped back shortly after) is that your client side code only alerts the error message if the error code is greater than zero.

Your server side code always sends back an error code of zero.

1. Change `data1` to `data` everywhere
2. Remove `if(servRet.error > 0)` or let the server side code send back a different number

Comment: I was not getting the return back to the success function at all. However, When I changed the URL to /MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php from "localhost/MyApp/server/user-data/moveUploadedFile.php";, things srarted working.

Answer (score -1):

1. Subtlety - If you have large json objects/arrays - you should send them as a simple string.
   1.1. You need JSON decode on server side.
2. Always make some sql injection escape first!
3. You can access your data as `$_POST['username']` for example. Dump your `$_POST` array.
4. When you send php data back to JS with `json_encode()` - you need adding a header too!!!

Code sample:

```
<?php
// Setting escaped data example. 
// You can use much more variants, like sprintf() for example.
$id = intval(trim($_POST['id']);
// Returning back the server responce.
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Comment: <?php
 // Setting escaped data example. 
 // You can use much more variants, like sprintf() for example.
 $id = intval(trim($_POST['id']);
 // Returning back the server responce.
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($your_array);

Comment: 1. The code does that. 2. There's no SQL database so that is nonsense. 3. The POST array is being dumped. 4. That's best practise but not strictly true.

Comment: I cannot format the code. There is some bug - I think. Or  I can not exit from the list. Sorry - see the code into the previous comment.

Comment: Just put a paragraph above the code sample, instead of making it a list item (since the code sample is a demonstration of the 4 points in the list, not a separate point).